# How to execute button click if PostBackUrl redirect to different server

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have a button which have a `PostBackUrl` url.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="https://www.vine.com/test.jsp" />
```

I want to create a asynchronous mail on the `click` on same button.I am using the `onclick="Button1_Click"` event but it's not working.

Please help me the easiest way to create this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

handle the redirect codebedind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do mail stuff here
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(@"https://www.vine.com/test.jsp");
}
```

Comment: If I don't wanna remove `PostBackUrl` then any other way ??

Comment: possible but difficult - add a `onClientClick`instead of a `onclick` and handle the mail send in a ajax called script/webmethod

Comment: because getting the error `{"Response is not available in this context."}` when I use the ` Response.Redirect` code. @fubo